# Please flag when you see spam answers for domain reference

Tags: discussion, spam

Lately we have been getting spam answers to unknown domains and I would encourage users to use caution before clicking on the links.  Please mark these as spam so we can investigate.  The mods will leave answers to known spam links.

Answer (score 2):

Spam domain from filerepairforum.com & illustrator.repair.

Answer (score 2):

Spam domain from: photonarnia.com